# how do I get my author ID photo to appear next to my site in google results?

Tags: wordpress, photo, google-plus, author

how do I get my author ID photo to appear next to my site in google? I have added my google  profile to my wordpress about me page and have added my wordpress blog to my google  contributes to section- am I missing something?
The odd thing was that the author id was showing for a couple of months before I had done anything to my blog or google+ page- then it disappeared and cant seem to regain it. Happy to talk about commissioning to problem as I have 4 blogs I need sorting out

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called [Google Authorship](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986).

1. Edit the [contributor section of your profile](https://plus.google.com/me/about/edit/co)
2. Add a link to your blog to the contributor section.
3. You will need to add markup to your articles that links to your profile and identifies you as the author. You might use [a Wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/google-authorship) to do this for you.

   The following whos you how to manually do this for any type of HTML page. You do this by setting a byline with a link to your profile or by using a LINK element in your page:

   ```
   by <a href="https://plus.google.com/106189723444098348646" rel="author">Larry Page</a>
   <!-- Alternatively, use the link element in your <HEAD> -->
   <link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/106189723444098348646" />
   ```
4. Test your authorship markup by using the [Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets). Confirm that it properly reads your authorship markup.
5. Wait for Google Search to pick this information in its index.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help,
U can upload photos to your WP users using this plugin (I've tried it on one of my sites, seems to work fine): http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-photo/.
Later on U can display the photo (or thumbnail) using one of the tags generated by this plugin 
(I've used userphoto() ).
So:
1. Install & activate the plugin.
2. Dashboard->Users. And choose the user which You'ld like to upload a photo for.
3. User userphoto() tag in the place U wish to display the photo (U can find instruction regarding the available tags in the plugin's link mentioned above).